Возникает ошибка ValueError при указанном значении max_date или min_date в KivyMD MDModalInputDatePicker
Пытаюсь создать окно выбора дат с ограничением по минимальной дате и максимальной.
при указании одного из параметров возникает ошибка ValueError, при указании обоих параметров - ошибка IndexError.
datepicker = MDModalInputDatePicker(mode='range',
                                    max_date=date.today(),
                                    min_date=date(2023, 4, 1),
                                    date_format='dd/mm/yyyy',
                                    )


start, end = input_dates[0] or start, input_dates1 or end
IndexError: list index out of range

datepicker = MDModalInputDatePicker(mode='range',
                                    max_date=date.today(),
                                    date_format='dd/mm/yyyy',
                                    


)


ValueError: None is not allowed for
MDModalInputDatePicker._current_month_name


Прошу прощения, на Python код
